# Optimus: Using optirun logs me out, then fails?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a Samsung QX411, with an Intel HD Graphics 5000 and a nVidia GeForce 520M GPU, both bridged with Optimus.  I'm running Ubuntu 15.04.

Now, here's my problem.  When I run `optirun glxinfo` for the first time after bootup, I'm immediately kicked back to the login screen.  If I log in again and run `optirun glxinfo` again, I get this error:

```
[   52.703355] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) NOUVEAU(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version.

[   52.703408] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Of course, this means I can't actually *use* Optimus, which is what I'm ultimately trying to do.

Any thoughts?