# Upgrading to newest nVidia drivers on a laptop that uses Optimus? (Ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, gpu

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on a laptop with an Intel HD Graphics 5000 and a nVidia GeForce 520M, joined by an Optimus.  I'm trying to upgrade my graphics drivers to the latest provided by the vendor so I can use [the new experimental build of Unity 3D](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/).

However, when I try switch to any driver besides the default open source one, `glxinfo` gives me this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  33
Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

...and then when I reboot, my graphics don't work, so I have to revert to the old drivers via the command line.  The thing is, I've been able to use Optimus on this laptop before (via `optirun`).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu is getting good at bundling vendor graphics drivers so having to download and install manually is not necessarily the go to solution.  Try this :

```
System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers
```

give it time to do its probes/lookups and it will respond with list of pre-loaded drivers from which you can pick an Nvidia if you wish.  This does work.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.  I'm back to the same issue that brought me here.  Also, this http://askubuntu.com/q/666277/61195