# Login Loop - "BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)" - 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, xorg

I was running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a manually installed NVIDIA 361 driver.  After upgrading the driver to v367 I am now locked out of Unity with a login loop with the following error in *.xsession-errors*:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  32
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

I also found this in the *Xorg* logs:

```
[ 2312.921302] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[ 2312.921304] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[ 2312.921305] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[ 2312.921305] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
           NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
```

And then this further down:

```
[  2850.609] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Dec 8 15:52:25 2015 +1000
[  2850.609] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  2850.706] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[  2850.706] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[  2850.706] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:02:00.0: -22
[  2850.706] (EE) No devices detected.
[  2850.706] (II) Applying OutputClass "nvidia" to /dev/dri/card0
[  2850.706]    loading driver: nvidia
[  2850.706] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2850.706] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2850.706] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2850.706] (==) Matched nvidia as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2850.706] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 4
[  2850.706] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 7
[  2850.706] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  2850.706] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  2850.708] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  2850.708] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[  2850.708] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[  2850.708] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2850.708] (II) UnloadModule: "nouveau"
[  2850.708] (II) Unloading nouveau
[  2850.708] (II) Failed to load module "nouveau" (already loaded, 21886)
[  2850.709] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2850.709] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2850.709] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2850.709] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Tue Dec 8 15:52:25 2015 +1000
[  2850.709] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[  2850.709] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  364.19  Tue Apr 19 13:48:55 PDT 2016
[  2850.709] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  2850.709] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2850.709] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[  2850.709] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
[  2850.709] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[  2850.709] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[  2850.709] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[  2850.709] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:02:00.0: -22
[  2850.709] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:02:00.0: -22
```

A web search of this error message does not yield many relevant results.

I have tried downgrading to v364 and then back to v361 to no avail
I have tried purging xserver-xorg, xserver-xorg-core, nvidia*, lightdm to no avail
I have tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop to no avail

A complete reformat and reinstall would be hugely disruptive and I want to avoid that at all costs.

The error message in *.xsession-errors* always remains the same.  How can I purge / restore / reset my settings and/or packages and/or libraries to a sane state without completely reformatting and reinstalling?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/a/666658/64957

Comment: My solution was http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321185/after-update-glx-works-only-for-root-nvidia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved the issue.  Although I attempted a manual *uninstall* of the manually installed 361 driver, it failed to clean-up all the shared objects and so what I was experiencing was essentially a library problem.

**After purging all NVIDIA packages** using `apt`, I resolved this as follows:

1. Locate all the 361 driver shared object files, excluding any trash folder, home folder and Steam games folder, by running:

   ```bash
   locate so.361.45 | egrep -vi "trash|steam|^/home"
   ```
2. Remove the suspicious shared object files (some contain the word `nvidia` while others contain just `nv`).
3. Run `ldconfig`.
4. Run `ldd $( which glxinfo )`.
5. Inspect the output of `ldd` and ensure that none of the entries point to any stale NVIDIA 361.45 shared objects.
6. Reboot.
7. Install the NVIDIA 364 driver via `apt`.
8. Reboot.

Comment: Wow! I was still on NVidia 304, but this morning, lightdm failed to log me in... I see that upgrading NVidia is a manual task. I upgraded to version 367 and now it works, after a full reboot (without the full reboot, it looks like the modules are not all properly reloaded automatically...)

Comment: I've had some automated success changing my nVidia driver via the _Additional Drivers_ GUI, but it seems more of a manual exercise directly via `apt`

Answer (score 9):

Adding `+iglx` to xserver-command in `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf`.

```
[SeatDefaults] 
# Dump core 
xserver-command=X -core +iglx
```

After which you either reboot or Ctrl-Alt-F1, login, and `sudo service lightdm restart`.

Works like a charm

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This fixed my problem when trying to run OpenGL windows in a chroot environment.