# SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, steam

I know that the question has already been asked several times on different forums but none of the potential solutions I have seen worked.

The problem is that when I try to install steam on lubuntu 18.04 i get this error message :

```
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

I have a Nvidia GTX 660 and I am using the nvidia-driver-396 package. I have tried different nvidia drivers and also the nouveau driver but it does not change anything.

I have installed steam using the steam-installer package.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ubuntu 16.04 gives "X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)" when running OpenGL programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o)