# X Error of failed request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) when executing gzserver within docker

Tags: xorg, display, docker

I'm trying to run gazebo from within a docker.
However, I don't need the display support.
When executing `gzserver`, I hit this problem:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

I found [this related topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o), however it does not cover the usage of docker.

Running `echo $DISPLAY` within docker returns `:0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable `DISPLAY=:0`.
Most probably this is set somewhere in the dockerfile as

```
ENV DISPLAY :0
```

or in the docker-compose.yml as

```
environment:
  - DISPLAY
```

If the display and rendering is not needed, remove the declarations above or unset this variable via

```
unset -v DISPLAY
```

in order to work around the problem.