# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS login loop (logged out right after entering password)

Tags: 16.04, login, auto-login

Right before this happened, I was updating some packages using conda (and sudo), and also install some addons for jupyter notebook (no idea if any of that is related to my problem or not). Something failed because my disk was completely full (the / directory had 100% usage). I thought this was in error becuase I had just deleted some stuff, so I rebooted. Now when I get to the login screen in ubuntu GUI, when I type in the password and press enter, the GUI goes away like it normally does, except 3 seconds later, it makes the clunky "error" sound and goes back. I can still log in to a terminal window with control alt F1. This login loop also happens when I try to login to the guest account (which doesn't even have a password).

What I have tried (none of this fixed the problem):

```
- Freed up disk space (I used sudo apt-get autoremove; I now have under 80% usage on all my drives)

- Restarting lightdm

- Removed /var/crash/*

- sudo chmod 777 ~/.ICEauthority

- sudo apt-get purge nvidia-* 

- chown username:username .Xauthority

- purging and reinstall lightdm

- Checking PATH in ~/.profile (PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" looks normal to me)

- rebooted after all these steps
```

My .xsession-errors file is:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  30
Current serial number in output stream:  31
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory  
cannot connect to brltty at :0    
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (1848) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (1840) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: logrotate main process (1679) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (1838) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (1771) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (1904) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (1905) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-application main process (1944) killed by TERM signal
```

I'm not really sure what those things mean, to be honest.

Edit: After about six hours of trying various things around ask ubuntu and reddit, I still couldn't get it. So I just reinstalled the OS (well, I installed the current version, 20. something).

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 will be out of support in a few days. There's no point in troubleshooting. Assuming you have backups simply install fresh a new LTS (20.04)

Comment: If you are 100 full on the disk no GUI can start.

Comment: Maybe this will help re install xserver-xorg-core etc - 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o