# 16.04 stuck in login loop after installing CUDA toolkit 10.1

Tags: 16.04, login, virtualization, cuda, esx

**Preface:** I am running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.15.0) in an ESXi virtual machine (version 6.7), and using PCI passthrough for a GTX 1080Ti. I am attempting to install the CUDA 10.1 toolkit, with Nvidia-418 drivers. I have tried 384 as well, and using apt install nvidia-current. Same result every time.

When I finish the CUDA installation and restart the machine, I am stuck at the login screen and cannot get to the desktop. Every time I type in my password, the login manager disappears for a few seconds, then a black screen, and then I am prompted again to enter my password. I even specified in the Ubuntu install to "Log in automatically", yet I always hit the login screen post CUDA installation.

I need the desktop to work, with the Nvidia drivers, in order to run a specific piece of software.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Changing ESXi settings. I have tried using ESXi 6.7, 6.5, and 6.0. I have also specified "hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = false". Additionally, I have disabled secure boot, and changed the boot option settings from "BIOS" to "EFI". No change with any of these adjustments.
- Installing VMware tools on the host machine
- Restarting the lightdm service
- Reconfiguring X server [via this guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2283795). It is important to note when I followed the guide, I did get two displays that showed up. The "Device" section of the xorg.conf file had the right BusID, but did not have the right driver. I changed it from "noveau" to "nvidia". Still no results
- Installing and running gdm3
- Running `startx` from a tty session
- (Attempting to) connect to the desktop using VNC
- Adding "nomodeset noveau.modeset=0" to GRUB
- Installing CUDA using both the runfile and the .deb
- Adding `+iglx` to [Xserver commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801440/login-loop-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-of-range-for-operation-16-04)

Oddly enough, I am able to run nvidia-smi post installation and see the graphics card appear. Unfortunately, I am unable to run the software I need to test without a GUI, so running it from tty is not an option.

I am not sure what log files to post, but here is my .xsession-errors log:

[Xsession-errors log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp6q1.png)

How should I proceed? I have been troubleshooting this issue for days and I have hit a wall. I cannot figure out what else to try.

Thank you!

Comment: `nvidia-current`does not do what you think, it installs a legacy long term support version.